# When to use the heap instead of the stack and when do variables go out of scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

Let's say I have this code

```
void foo()
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

does x disappear from memory(goes out of scope) when the function returns?

If I make this

```
void foo()
{
    int *x = new int
    *x = 0;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

is that the correct way to make x not disappear when the function ends?
Also, since that variable is declared inside the function, how do I access it in the main after the function has been executed?

When should I use delete? Does the memory allocated on the heap become free when the program is closed or I have to manually do that?

Comment: too broad topic. first learn basic c++ from a good book/tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

1)  Yes, variables declared in the function goes out of scope once stack unwinding happens.

2)  To allocate the memory in the heap yes, you can use 'new' allocator.

3)  To avail the memory allocated from anywhere in the program,  either you return the pointer from the function itself, or assing in the global variable.

4) When you the variable is no more usable, then  you can delete with 'delete' operator.

Hope this helps!!.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes `x` goes out of scope when the function exits.
2. Yes. The technical name for "not disappear" is a memory leak. In this code example you lose the pointer, since it goes out of scope after the function as discussed in 1, so you won't be able to delete the memory. Smart pointers are much better.

In general, to access something from a function when the function call has finished, you are best off returning what you want.

e.g.

```
int * foo()
{
    int *x = new int;
    *x = 0;
    cout << x << endl;
    return x;
}
```

I suggest you read up on smart pointers instead though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, `x` goes out of scope when `foo()` returns. However `x` is automatic, which means it is probably allocated on the stack, and possibly its contents will remain for some time in the same place of memory - but you never know how long it will last until some other function overwrites it.
   And with sufficient level of optimization such simple `x` will be allocated in a CPU register, so it may get overwritten even before the function terminates, just after `out<<x` execution.
2. Yes, `x` goes out of scope when `foo()` returns, so you loose the access to the variable allocated on a heap. You can, however, `return x` from your function, or store the pointer value in some external variable, so it might be retrieved and used after the `foo()` termination.
   You should use `delete` when you no longer need a variable.
   Unfreed memory is returned automatically to the system together with the whole heap when the program teminates. However, if your allocated objects reserve some external resources (IO streams, system semaphores etc) it's good to `delete` them so those resources are released properly.

BTW, if `x` is a pointer and you want to printout the `int` value rather than its memory address, you should use a dereference operator on the pointing variable:  `cout << *x`.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer doing like this, in this order:

1. Copy or move the result of the function outside.
2. Use smart pointers if the type is being used polymorphically or cannot be copied/moved.

   - Try to use `std::unique_ptr` when you can.
   - Use `std::shared_ptr` when you must.

In general, in my experience, you can make types movable most of the time.
Copyability depends on the kind of class you are managing. Classes that access resources
such as filesystem, threads, locks, etc. are difficult to copy or it makes no sense to copy them.